# Join two files with matching columns

Tags: awk, join

File1.txt

```
    id                            No
    gi|371443199|gb|JH556661.1| 7907290
    gi|371443198|gb|JH556662.1| 7573913
    gi|371443197|gb|JH556663.1| 7384412
    gi|371440577|gb|JH559283.1| 6931777
```

File2.txt

```
 id                              P       R       S
 gi|367088741|gb|AGAJ01056324.1| 5       5       0
 gi|371443198|gb|JH556662.1|     2       2       0
 gi|367090281|gb|AGAJ01054784.1| 4       4       0
 gi|371440577|gb|JH559283.1|     21      19      2
```

output.txt

```
 id                              P       R       S  NO
 gi|371443198|gb|JH556662.1|     2       2       0  7573913
 gi|371440577|gb|JH559283.1|     21      19      2  6931777
```

File1.txt has two columns & File2.txt has four columns. I want to join both files which has unique id (array[1] should match in both files (file1.txt & file2.txt)
and give ouput only matched id (see output.txt).

I have tried `join -v <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)`. Any help with awk or join commands requested.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`join` works great:

```
$ join <(sort File1.txt) <(sort File2.txt) | column -t | tac
 id                           No       P   R   S
 gi|371443198|gb|JH556662.1|  7573913  2   2   0
 gi|371440577|gb|JH559283.1|  6931777  21  19  2
```

ps. does ouput column order matter?

if yes use:

```
$ join <(sort 1) <(sort 2) | tac | awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$5,$2}' | column -t
 id                           P   R   S  No
 gi|371443198|gb|JH556662.1|  2   2   0  7573913
 gi|371440577|gb|JH559283.1|  21  19  2  6931777
```

Comment: works great. column order doesn't matter

Comment: What's the reason for including `tac`?

Comment: That's because `sort` places header string at the end. Actually it's dirty solution. And in general case header may go into the middle of the output. However it works here.

Answer (score 11):

One way using `awk`:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
## Process first file of arguments. Save 'id' as key and 'No' as value
## of a hash.
FNR == NR {
    if ( FNR == 1 ) { 
        header = $2
        next
    }   
    hash[ $1 ] = $2
    next
}

## Process second file of arguments. Print header in first line and for
## the rest check if first field is found in the hash.
FNR < NR {
    if ( $1 in hash || FNR == 1 ) { 
        printf "%s %s\n", $0, ( FNR == 1 ? header : hash[ $1 ] ) 
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk File1.txt File2.txt | column -t
```

With following result:

```
id                           P   R   S  NO
gi|371443198|gb|JH556662.1|  2   2   0  7573913
gi|371440577|gb|JH559283.1|  21  19  2  6931777
```

Comment: +65535 for keeping the original line order. :-)