# Concatenate matching ids from two files, with other columns from both files

Tags: text-processing

I want to match ids from file A with file B, to save it in third file with columns that belongs to both files. I have tried almost all awks that I found, but somehow doesnt work properly. I would appreciate you help!

`fileA`:

```
id;name
1;"sam"
4;"jon"
```

`fileB`:

```
id;surname
5;"smith"
1;"khon"
```

`file3`:

```
id;name;surname
1;"sam";"khon"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you sort your files and use `join` instead of `awk`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43420/194382

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join two files with matching columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43417/join-two-files-with-matching-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this would be a job for `join`. However, `join` requires sorted input and `sort` will put numbers before letters in all locales I am aware of (please correct me if that's not true). So `join` can only get you part of the way there:

```
$ join -t';' <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB)
1;"sam";"khon"
id;name;surname
```

You could get around this by joining the the first line of each file first and then the rest:

```
$ join -t';' <(head -n1 fileA) <(head -n1 fileB)
id;name;surname
$ join -t';' <(tail -n+2 fileA | sort) <(tail -n+2 fileB | sort)
1;"sam";"khon"
```

Then, grouping these in a subshell and redirecting the output gives you your desired output:

```
 $ ( join -t';' <(head -n1 fileA) <(head -n1 fileB); join -t';' <(tail -n+2 fileA | sort) <(tail -n+2 fileB | sort))
id;name;surname
1;"sam";"khon"
```

So you could do this:

```
( 
    join -t';' <(head -n1 fileA) <(head -n1 fileB); 
    join -t';' <(tail -n+2 fileA | sort) <(tail -n+2 fileB | sort)
) > file3
```

---

Alternatively, you can indeed do it in `awk`:

```
$ awk -F';' '(NR==FNR){data[$1]=$1";"$2; next} 
             ($1 in data){print data[$1]";"$2}' fileA fileB 
id;name;surname
1;"sam";"khon"
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much!!!! This with awk works great. with join i have to sort the other columns, will take a lot on that later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv --fs ";" join -j id -f fileA.csv fileB.csv >file3.csv
```

you have

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | surname |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | sam  | khon    |
+----+------+---------+
```

Some notes:

- `--fs` to set field separator;
- `-j` to set join field.

Comment: Does it actually add all those extra `-`, `|` and `+`? Is there an option to avoid that?

Comment: This also works! Thank you very much!